# Trying to access Core Data Model's NSNumber property gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsnumber

I have an entity called Weather in my Core Data in the following form:

[xcdatamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoxzi.png)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface WeatherModel : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cityName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * temperature;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * humidity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * windSpeed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * iconId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * units;

@end
```

I save the instances of this model to Core Data as follows:

```
WeatherModel *bookmarkWeatherModel = (WeatherModel*)[DatabaseHelper insertNewEntityWithName:@"Weather" andContext:self.weatherManagedObjectContext];

[bookmarkWeatherModel setLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0]];
[bookmarkWeatherModel setLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0]];
[bookmarkWeatherModel setCityName:@"CityA"];
NSLog(@"%@", bookmarkWeatherModel.cityName);
NSLog(@"%@", bookmarkWeatherModel.latitude);

[DatabaseHelper saveCoreData:self.weatherManagedObjectContext];
```

However whenever I try to access any of the NSNumber properties (even after calling saveCoreData method),
[I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYsyn.png)

insertNewEntityWithName method in DatabaseHelper:

```
+ (NSManagedObject *)insertNewEntityWithName:(NSString *)entityName
                                  andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObject *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    return entity;
}
```

I tried accessing every single property in my model and only properties that throw this error are of type NSNumber. The others work just fine.

Comment: Are they setup correctly as numbers in your model?

Comment: Also FYI you can safely change them from NSNumber to the primitive type (Int, Double, whatever is set in the model) safety.  All you have to do is change the type of the property and core-data figures it out.  This can make it easier to not have to unwrap NSNumbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I wrote the code for the model by hand. I solved the problem by generating the code automatically. I did that by choosing my entity in xcdatamodel, filling in the Class Name(WeatherModel) and Codegen(Manual/None) in data model inspector and then choosing Editor>Create NSManagedObject Subclass.